# Responsive navigation — from one line to 3-fluid-columns?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, multiple-columns

When using a standard `<nav> & <ul>` it is easy to create navigation that appears on a single line:

[image]

*Desktop: http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/Be9ma/1/*

Since this is for a responsive layout, on smaller displays, the navigation will contract into 3-columns (and maybe even 2) with media queries (not featured in code):

[image]

*Mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/Be9ma/*

**But it's not spaced aesthetically:**

Since the widths of the `nav li` elements are 33.3333% then the spacing is messed up — some navigation items are long, and some short. But the spacing isn't fluid.

**How can I adjust each column to be only as wide as the widest element + padding/margins?** That is, without separating or nesting the `ul` out — which would break the semantics, and when viewed on a wide display.

Here's the simple HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Very Long Link</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Also Long Link</li>
    <li>Email</li>
    </ul>
</nav>​
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
nav {
    clear: both;
    background: pink;
}

    nav ul {
        padding: 20px 10px 0 30px;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    nav li {
        font-variant: small-caps;
        text-decoration: underline;
        list-style: none;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        padding: 0 0 30px 0;
        margin: 0; 
        width: 33.33333%;
        float: left;
}
```

Curious to hear your ideas. Thank you in advance!

P.S. I would like to stress **cross-browser compatibility and semantics**.

Comment: use a percentage based padding or margin?  Not entirely sure what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some @media queries for mobile.

http://jsfiddle.net/bf9cB/
You'll need to open/contract the center bar to see the change

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    nav li { max-width:160px; text-align:center } /* This would only allow 3 to fit */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    nav li { max-width:106px; text-align:center }
}
```

Betting the font size will be a factor at 320px wide (FYI).
Your problem reminds me of a book I read recently: ["Mobile First"](http://www.abookapart.com/products/mobile-first). In a nutshell: start your build at mobile, and work 'up' from there. Def worth checking out.

Comment: It IS the question....they need to set MAX/MIN-WIDTH in order to keep the spacing nice. If "XX" and "XXXX" have a max-width set to 4X, "XX" won't take on an arbitrary/rigid width. In a 100% layout, 6 columns would translate to "16.667%". "33.333" seems right for a small display, but the gaps in the NAV look bad. Can't have it both ways -- unless there is some type of control in place -- ie setting a max for the parent, kids, etc. (Aside -- it would also help aesthetics to not have 4 letter navigation mixed with a twelve letter sibling...just sayin')

Comment: @Matt - how do you tell me it's not the question, when your own comment says, "Not entirely sure what you're looking to do."??

Comment: Ahh..I missed `106` and `160` being different values and thought you were only answering with the media queries suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Dawson, yup, have been building this mobile first (and am fond of the book), but was asking this more with HTML semantics in mind as well (hence why I started with the desktop example). Your example is great, thanks! A question — why the second media query? Also, since your solution relies on setting `text-align: center`, the long links I have are different lengths, which will look a bit odd. No way to left-justify **and** center the columns, huh?

Comment: **P.S.** Another consideration is having a decent amount of padding around each for **click-ability on mobile** — in your version, it seems that each column is the same width in that regard, and doesn't adjust to the length of text, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/bf9cB/4/ — any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s3Xd3/ . As to the text-align...I don't think it will matter where widths are concerned, but it doesn't look right. Oddly enough, I'll bet the nav isn't aligned "right" on a large display either -- but our eyes don't pick it up like they do when everything is compacted in a narrower area. When we're 'zoomed in' so are the variations/imperfections

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on the paddin'?

Comment: Touch areas are supposed to be a minimum of 44px x 44px? I threw up some code I use for that. http://jsfiddle.net/Txt6K/. Also had to adjust your `ul` CSS, and some other things (minor), but the idea is visibly apparent.